# How to manage deployment across servers in IIS 7.5 on a clustered environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, setup-deployment

I have 3 environments for my IIS apps.

1. Dev - Debug
2. Staging - Debug
3. Production (Active Active cluster) - Release

When I am deploying, I am making a lot of mistakes like restarting the wrong APP, or deleting the wrong version, or deploying debug version to production.
I have to be more efficient.

When I work on linux, I have a bash script that takes the branch from my svn and deploy the staging.
After the staging was going through success  QA, another bash script will deploy to the production server(s)

What options do i have in IIS on win server 2008 r2?

Thanks

Comment: You can do the same (script file) in Windows. Try PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's web deploy, which simplifies deployment and synchronization of Web applications to IIS servers. 
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy